# Two UIButtons on rightView of Textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a problem that only one button gets displayed right now. I would like the "Vergessen?" Button to be showed unless user types something in. While editing the "Eye" Button should appear. Right now only one of them gets displayed and I don't know why. And is there an easy way to change the "eye" Button Size?

```
func createForgetButton () {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Vergessen?", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.vergessenTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 19.0)
    passwordTextField.rightView = button
    passwordTextField.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing

}

func createTogglePassword () {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "eyeOpen"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(togglePassword(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    passwordTextField.rightView = button
    passwordTextField.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
}
```

//subclass for my Textfield:

```
override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let offset = -20
    let width  = 125
    let height = 125
    let x = Int(bounds.width) - width - offset
    let y = offset
    let rightViewBounds = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    return rightViewBounds
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t see any frame (CGRect) set for your vergessen button. You may make it work programmatically by setting a proper frame, yet I highly recommend to use storyboard and constraints for this sake.

Comment: mmm ok, might try it like this

Comment: Good luck, dien UI ist Shön! By the way ☺️

Comment: danke :D appreciated!